# Connect Device with Android wear emulator over adb connect

Tags: android, tcp, adb, android-virtual-device

i wanted to connect my AndroidDevice with my AndroidWear emulator.
IF i connect my Device via USB-cable, and enter

> adb forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601

it works.

But if i connect my device over

> adb connect 192.168.2.111

the device is connecting to my Computer correctly.

But if i want to forward it now, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
adb -s 192.168.2.111:5555 forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601

where 192.168.2.111 is your handheld ip address.
after executing this command, launch the android wear application on handheld and click "connect to emulator" in action overflow.

It works for me.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

I was looked this solution few hours and i adding some more info:

at description of ADB commands also says, that the "SN" in:

```
adb -s serial_number_of_device
```

for SN it is also ip:port so you can use this for commanding some more devices

```
adb -s 192.168.1.101:5555 [command]
adb -s localhost:62001 [command]  
#ex. $ adb -s localhost:62025 shell netcfg     for second window of Nox
```

I hope that is for a bit more usefull now...